# Label placement on filters

Tags: user-expectation, filter, labels, copywriting

Why almost all filters I find have their labels inside, as a placeholder? When the users select a value they lose context since the label is no longer visible.

Isn't it a better option to put the label always above the filter? Just like with text fields.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean. Can you show an example?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it's just space consideration.

Filters are usually not a prevalent part of the form, so they shouldn't take too much space, so trying to optimize the space, they usually go for the more compact solution.

---

Now putting labels inside the fields, I think, has been popularized by the rise of Material Design system. [They do use both ways now](https://m3.material.io/components/text-fields/specs), tho - showing the label inside the field, but once you enter a value - above the field without changing the size of the field:
[image]

Note that, for example, Carbon Design System [advises against](https://carbondesignsystem.com/components/text-input/usage/#main-elements) using placeholders as labels:

> Optional placeholder text provides hints or examples of what to enter. Placeholder text disappears after the user begins entering data into the input. As such, **it should not** be used as a replacement for a persistent label nor should it contain crucial information.